# magento 2 global search page css error

Tags: magento2

While searching for product and if product not exist then no issue but when product found then css not loading and giving error

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at ?q=Dummy:117
site is not on local its on live[image] 
And this is only happening to this page, other all pages are working fine

Comment: Bit of a guess but this looks like an issue with list.phtml seems to stop rendering around the price. Maybe check there.

Comment: app/design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml maybe temporarily rename that file see it it works. If it does then there is an issue with something on there when used in search.

Comment: yes,by renaming list.phtml page  is displaying but default css is applying not my custom  css. for that what should I do ?

Comment: that is to be expected as we just reverted it to normal to see that problem lies there. I would rename it back make a backup of it and remove bits of code that are custom until you find the problem

Comment: It may be showing in logs however either on server apache / nginx or within var/log of magento which may give you more information

Comment: in var/log/system.log file getting below error
main.INFO: Theme layout update file '/home/smashedmedia/public_html/demo/app/design/frontend/golf/theme_golf/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml' is not valid.
Extra content at the end of the document
 Line: 4 [] []

Comment: This is something separate and will apply to the homepage